# How to build a project under the src directory of Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qmake, vulkan

I found a .pro file  5.12.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\platforms\windows\windows.pro and opened it in Qt Creator. After configuring a MingW kit, I tried to build the project. But I got this error；

```
 error: vulkan/vulkan.h: No such file or directory

 #include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
```

Do I need to configure something before building the project? I do not want the vulkan support, just want to compile it successfully. I remember if I build the whole Qt src, I need to run a command like "configure xxxxx" in the src directory. Now I do not want to build whole Qt, just this project. There is a line in windows.pro that seems related to this problem.

```
qtConfig(vulkan): QT += vulkan_support-private
```

How should I do to remove the need for the vulkan stuff in order to build it successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to configure things. I suggest you read up on [Building Qt 5 from source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html) to understand what is involved.